# Traversing through a LinkedList in an odd way?

Tags: java, string, list, find, traversal

I want to be able to find the data immediately before an given piece of data.
For example, say you had a list of names:

```
Bob, Tommy, Scott, Frank, Evan, Ryan, Jessy, Alex, Abner, Edward, Smith, Adam
```

A hypothetical method find() is passed a name, and returns the name immediately before it, sequentially.

For example, you run find(Ryan), which has a desired result of returning Evan.
How would you accomplish this? Since there is no iterator, I am unsure how this would be done.

Comment: Have you considered using a `ListIterator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a simple snippet that would fix your issue

```
LinkedList<String> yourListWithName = new LinkedList<String>();
//Fill your list

ListIterator<String> listIterator = yourListWithName.listIterator();

String previous = null;

while(listIterator.hasNext()) {

    if(listIterator.hasPrevious())
    {

        previous = listIterator.previous();
        listIterator.next();
    }

    String current = listIterator.next();

    if(current.equals(yourReceivedName))
        //Your algorithm
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `indexOf`:

```
public String find(List<String> names, String name) {
    int index = names.indexOf(name);
    return index > 0 ? names.get(index - 1) : null;
}
```

However this is pretty inefficient as both `indexOf` and `get` require iteration. For relatively small lists this is unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard yes it does http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html